# Mockin apollo-link-state queries

Tags: mocking, graphql, apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client

I've found some resources on how to mock regular queries with `react-apollo`. An example is the code below:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider } from 'react-apollo';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { addMockFunctionsToSchema, makeExecutableSchema } from 'graphql-tools';

const schemaString = `
  type Model {
    id: ID!
  }

  type Query {
    model(modelId: ID!): Model
  }
`;

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs: schemaString });
const mocks = {};
addMockFunctionsToSchema({ schema, mocks });
const link = new SchemaLink({ schema });
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

But how to mock `apollo-link-state` queries, i.e. those marked `@client`?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else ends up here: my solution was not to mock them. Since it is local I set it up the same way as in production.